# What does fdisk's Start and End values mean when looking at a compact flash

Tags: fdisk, mbr, flash-memory

I'm analyzing a compact flash using fdisk and by comparing it to the contents of the partition table on the CF's master boot record.  I don't understand what the "Start" and "End" columns mean.  Some of the documentation that I read says that it means the starting sector and ending sector of that partition, but when I compare the fdisk output to the address of the partition in the MBR partition table, the result don't seem to agree.

Fdisk -l reports that the first partition starts at 3 but ends at 2241.

[image]

However a hexdump of the partition table in the MBR shows that the partition starts at sector 0x800 according to the LBA address.  While the CHS addres shows Cylinder 1, Head 1, Sector 3.

[image]

So what does fdisk mean by Start 3, and End 2241?

Comment: @zevzek Thanks.  I changed the units in fdisk and it makes more sense now.   Now it shows start at 2048 which corresponds to the LBA address of 0x800!  But still not sure why fdisk when reporting in Units = cylinders, why it shows the Start cylinder at 3, but the MBR partition table CHS addressing shows Head=1, Sector=3, and Cylinder=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 6's `fdisk` still defaults to using cylinders as the default units when displaying the partition table. As commented by zevzek, this is obsolete and you should use `fdisk -u=sectors -l` to better match the reality of modern storage devices and also how later versions of `fdisk` display it by default.

The CHS values in the actual partition table have pretty restrictive maximum values:

- the *cylinders* field is just 10 bits wide (= values 0-1023)
- the *heads* field is 8 bits wide (= values 0-255)
- the *sectors* field is 6 bits wide (= values 0-63)

So from your partition table, the start CHS (3 bytes) begins at location 0x1bf, with beginning H = 1, S = 3 and C = 1. This does not look correct.

Location 0x1c2 is the partition type (0x83), and immediately after that is the end CHS value (3 bytes) at location 0x1c3 onwards.

The second red frame in your hex dump is not pointing at the correct location:
the value at 0x1c3 is the end H value (0x14 = 20).

The value at 0x1c4 specifies the end sector value in the bottom 6 bits, and the two most significant bits of the end cylinder value in the top 2 bits. So 0xe8 = 11 101000 in binary, so the end S would be 40.The top two bits of the end C value represent a hexadecimal digit 3.

The value at 0x1c5 specifies the low byte of the end C value: together with the high two bits from the previous byte, the end cylinder value is 0x3b4 = 948.

(**These values would represent a partition of only about 378 MB, so compared to the 4-byte partition size value later the partition table, the end CHS value in the partition table is clearly complete nonsense.**)

But no matter how you slice it, this creates a limit at 7.87 GiB / 8.45 GB, at which points the bit values of the CHS fields in the partition table become all-ones, and those fields cannot represent any values larger than that.

This was further complicated by the IDE disk controller specification having a *different* set of CHS limits: an IDE controller could accept CHS values of up to 65536 cylinders (0-65535) and 255 (1-255) sectors, but only up to 16 (0-15) heads. If you just use the CHS values as-is, then together with the MBR limits, this would cause a limit at just 504 MiB / 528.4 MB.

Because of this, since July 1994, there has been a geometry translation convention to adapt the CHS values to the current use case. So the 2242 cylinders, 21 heads and 40 sectors are what the hardware says is the real geometry, and the values used in the partition table are based on translated, *fake* geometry in order to make the values fit in the fields of the partition table and the oldest BIOS system calls. This translation would usually involve choosing a number N, dividing the physical C value by N and multiplying the physical H value by N. The value of N would often be 2, 4, 8, or 15. (Yes, 15 instead of 16, to work around a bug in MS-DOS, old versions of Windows, and some old BIOSes.)

And when going beyond 8.45 GB, the CHS values are useless anyway, so any modern OS will usually straight up **ignore the CHS values**, and instead will use the 4-byte values of the LBA number of the first block of the partition and the total number of blocks in the partition to actually define the partition's location and size. Those 4-byte values should always be exact and unambiguous.

While using the classic 512-byte sector size, those 4-byte values will be enough for disk sizes up to (2^32 - 1) blocks in size, or in other words, just under 2 TiB, or 2.19 TB.

In the case of your partition, your second red frame in the hex dump actually points at 0x1c6 onwards, which is the LBA# of the first block of the partition: since it's represented in little-endian format, the value is 0x800 in hex, or 2048 in decimal. This follows the modern standard convention of starting the first partition at exactly 1 MiB from the beginning of the disk.

The length of the partition is specified starting from offset 0x1ca, and is 0x1cb000 = 1 880 064 blocks, or 918 MiB / 940 MB.

You can see that even the hardware-reported CHS geometry of `21 heads, 40 sectors/track, 2242 cylinders` results in just 2242 * 40 * 21 = 1 883 280 sectors, or 1883280 * 512 = 964 249 360 bytes, while the actual disk capacity is reported as 964 **583 424** bytes.

This is another indication that the CHS "geometry" is just an approximation for legacy devices and OSs, while the exact capacity is something different.

I guess `fdisk` just does everything using the LBA representation, and when requested to display the partition start and end values as cylinders, just calculates them based on the LBA position and size values, completely ignoring the start/end CHS values in the partition table. Likewise, the `Blocks` column seems to be actually displaying the size of the partition in base-2 kilobytes.

Comment: Nice explanation.   Not to be pedantic however, but according to what i'm reading, byte 0x1BF is the Head, 0x1C0 is the sector and 0x1C1 is the cylinder.  So in my case, H=1, S=3, C=1.  Don't know if that's an outdated convention??  Anyways, I would have expected fdisk to show the starting cylinder as 1, not 3, since the 3 is in the sector bit.  Here are links to the sources I'm quoting. https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/PartTables.htm and https://slideplayer.com/slide/11116673/ at 25 seconds

Comment: Anyhow, I'm mostly just trying to learn.  I realize that LBA is modern method of addressing drives, but I'd like to be able to make sense of what I'm seeing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oops, you're correct. The end CHS in the partition table is obviously nonsense, so I should have looked at the start CHS more carefully too. And yes, your decoding is correct and the start CHS does not make sense either.

Comment: Hmm. So your thinking is that the CHS values are just random nonsense.  I was expecting some sort of logical division of the flash memory into CHS values.

Comment: Probably created by some hurriedly-programmed piece of card initialization code at the card factory or in the firmware of some device or other that has most recently initialized the card. "The partition table created works for Windows, it's good enough, get the code into production!" In a well-made partition table, one would expect the partition entry to be internally consistent, so that the start/end CHS values would either result in the size identified by the 4-byte size value, or be known placeholders, but in this case they're really neither of those.